# Check the position on analog servo

Tags: motor, analog, servo

In analog servo, how to set the position with hands then check the position in raspberry pi,yes i know potentiometer can do that but i want with servo motor.

Now, i can increase decrease the speed of servo motor.

If some how it change its rotation how i am gone reset

I am using raspberry pi zero w.
Software language: java (pi4j).
My servo motor's name:sm-s4315r(analog servo).

Comment: Can you couple a rotary encoder to the shaft?

Comment: Your question is not clear. The servo has a potentiometer built in. You just read the position using that.

Comment: That's not an "Analog Servo". It has a digital PWM input which determines its rotation speed.

Comment: @Transistor - that's a "continuous rotation" type - it converts the PWM input to a direction & speed of rotation, not a position - so there's unlikely to be a pot inside.

Comment: If  there is no position sensor it's indeed not possible to know the position.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the published specifications for the sm-s4315r are poor. Sending a 1.5 ms control pulse tells the servo to stop.

It appears that normal operation assumes a continuous pulse train of about 50 pulses per second. Pulses shorter than 1.5 ms result in continuous rotation in the clockwise direction. Pulses longer than 1.5 ms result in counterclockwise rotation. Speed is inversely proportional to pulse width for the clockwise direction and directly proportional to pulse width in the counterclockwise direction. Supply-voltage change within a specified range also has an effect on speed.

The effect of applying power without sending control pulses is undefined. It seems possible that the result may be rotation at maximum speed in the clockwise direction.

It seems unlikely that there is any way to verify the speed, direction of rotation or position without adding shaft speed/position sensor.

There seems to be a "rest point" position adjustment, but I didn't' find a clear explanation of its function. A comment has convinced me that that this device has no positioning capability and that there is no way to "reset" or make it return to a specific position. If that is a requirement, a different servo or an added position sensor and external control programming is needed.

Comment: There is no *positional* "rest point" for such a device, any mention of that you are seeing is a holdover from the fact that it is a closed loop position device with a servo amp chip intended for that purpose, which has instead been hacked by the manufacturer or seller to disconnect the feedback potentiomater from the shaft and turn it into a crudely speed controlled device - perhaps by simply replacing it with a trimmer pot below a screwdriver hole in the lower case.

Comment: It may be that the "rest point" adjustment adjusts the pulse width corresponding to zero speed. It also seems possible that that bit of positional performance has been retained in the hacking. I suspect that the only physical hack is the removal of the mechanical rotation stop, and all else is firmware.

Comment: A firm and absolute "no" on your later suspicion.  The actual connection between the feedback pot and the shaft has been severed, **there is no residual position behavior at all**.  It is however true that moving the disconnected feedback pot (or its replacement trimmer, or changing the values of a replacing fixed divider) would alter the input pulse width at which the error output of the servo amp tends towards zero.  Given the usage of innacurate oscillators in the servo and perhaps the driving MCU that is often needed.

Comment: Worth noting that these continuous rotation servos are a "hobby helper" type of product with well known behavior, marketed to inexperienced builders.  Guessing what they do from a perspective of first principles but no familiary is counter productive, because it distracts from the only message that actually matters to an inexperienced user, which is simply **"this is the wrong motor for your purpose"**

Comment: Fair enough. I wasn't entirely guessing, I was trying to interpret a description I read and things I remembered from  attempting to physically troubleshoot something designed by someone else.

Answer (score 0):

You can't without adding a position sensor or bringing out the potentiometer leads so your ADC can read them (but even then it might not work unless the servo is happy with no PWM pulse signal so that it will just sit there and not try to move to a position.)

Comment: That particular servo is not likely to have an internal pot. It's a continuous rotation type, not a position type.